# Not able to display a gridview in another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am trying to display a course table which has one to money relationship with students table by using gridview under gridview.
but it not showing the elements of second table.

This .aspx webform

```
         <asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="courseid" HeaderText="courseid" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="coursename" HeaderText="coursename" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="students">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Bind("students") %>' AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                             <Columns>
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" />
                             </Columns>
                         </asp:GridView>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>

         </asp:GridView>
```

These are the table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[courses] (
     [courseid]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [coursename] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([courseid] ASC) );
```

This is second table students

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[students] (
     [rollno]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
     [gender]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
     [courseid] INT            NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([rollno] ASC),
     CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.students_dbo.courses_courseid] FOREIGN KEY ([courseid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[courses] ([courseid]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

code in .cs file

```
grid1.DataSource = courses.ToList();
grid1.DataBind();
```

In Output : it is not showing any data in student column

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the gridview within the main gridview does not have its datasource set. To do this, you would have to use the FindControl method to find the gridview, then bind it to a datasource.